# Mongo Find slows down

Tags: database, mongodb, go

I am using the mongo Db package for golang to  find a document. When I run multiple readMongo functions in go routines, the time taken to run the readMongo function increases. Is this a I/O limit of my machine? The documents i'm reading are less then 0.5MB.

```
func main(){

   go readMongo()
   go readMongo()
   go readMongo()

}

func go readMongo(){

  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
  defer cancel()
  client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
   if err != nil{
    //handle err
    }

     t1:=time.Now()
   collection := client.Database("Data").Collection("myCollection")

   if err := collection.FindOne(ctx,bson.M{"_id": "myKey"}).Decode(&data); err!= nil{}
  t2:=time.Now()
   fmt.Println(t2.sub(t1).Milliseconds())
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: connect to the db once, and use the same client for all the goroutines. The mongodb client manages the connection pooling.

With increased concurrency, the performance of individual reads will decrease mainly because of the network bandwidth. All parallel reads will share the same connection to the database, causing slowdowns. In your example, you are reading through multiple connections in parallel, causing the reads to share the network bandwidth. In real-life production loads, the database traffic is usually random and this slowdown for each individual goroutine is not so predictable.

Comment: I tried using the same client for all go routines. I still experience a slow down as the number of go routines increases

Comment: As I said, there will be a slowdown because all goroutines are sharing the same network connection.

Comment: Thank You. What is a possible solution?

Comment: With large enough data, you can use mongodb sharding so different databases and connection would be handling different queries. In your case, there is not solution, If you share network connection with multiple threads, you will see slowdown in each thread.